# Execute PHP functions in tags <script> in HTML using ScriptCase

Tags: javascript, php, scriptcase

I'm using a Blank Application in Scriptcase. I'm trying to add a blur event listener to "DNI" field in the HTML code, the user set an identification number in this field. When occurs the event, I consume an API, the API's response is the complete name of the owner of that identification number. The listener is added correctly, but the function is not called. What did I wrong?

The code setted in the Blank Application:

```
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet'>
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: 'Roboto';
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <title>CLBS | Registro de Usuario</title>
    </head>
    <body style="overflow: hidden !important">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row mt-5">
                <div class="col-6" style="border-radius: 5px !important; border: solid 1px #F3F3F3 !important">
                    <div class="row" style="background-color: #485EA2 !important; height: 40px !important">
                        <label class="col-12 col-form-label"><b style="color: white !important; font-size: 16px !important">Registro de Usuario</b></label>
                    </div>
                    
                    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
                        <div class="row mt-2">
                            <label class="col-form-label col-4"><b>DNI</b></label>
                            <div class="col-7">
                                <input id="input_dni" type="text" class="form-control" style="height: 27px !important" name="input_dni">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>              
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            const inputDNI = document.querySelector('#input_dni');
            
            inputDNI.addEventListener("blur", () => {
                const dni = inputDNI.value;
                //console.log(dni);
                var result ="<?php buscarEnReniec(dni); ?>";
                document.write(result);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
<?php

function buscarEnReniec($dni){
    echo $dni;
    sc_select (user, "SELECT nombres FROM pru_seg_usuarios WHERE nro_documento = " . $dni);

    if(count({user} -> fields) === 0) {
        $curl = curl_init();
        $token = 'token';

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
          CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.apis.net.pe/v2/reniec/dni?numero=' . $dni,
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
          CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
          CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
          CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 2,
          CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
          CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
          CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
          CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Referer: https://apis.net.pe/consulta-dni-api',
            'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token
          ),
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);

        curl_close($curl);

        $persona = json_decode($response, true);

        echo $persona;
    } else {
        $params = array(
            'title' => 'Aviso',
            'type' => 'warning',
            'timer' => '2000',
            'showConfirmButton' => false,
            'position' => 'top-end',
            'toast' => true
        );

        sc_alert('Ya existe un usuario con el nro de documento ingresado.', $params);
    }
}
```

I hope that someone can help me. Maybe it is a basic question but I'm a beginner using this tool.

Comment: You can't simply pass a variable between JS and php like that, they are two entirely separate languages and execution environments (one in the browser, one on the server). If you want to make php do something after some JavaScript code has run, you need to make the browser send a http request to the server to trigger the php script. Any php you embed in your JS directly will run _before_ the JS, while the page is still being generated. And you simply cannot reference a variable from one language in the others that makes no sense. It's like trying to talk to a zebra in French

Comment: but how can i do that?

Comment: @ADyson no, that don't answer my question :c

Comment: `but how can i do that`...how can you do what? I said already, if you want to trigger some PHP to execute after JS has run, you need to make a new HTTP request to the server. You can do that by using AJAX, or causing a form to be submitted, or causing the browser to navigate to a new URL - all the ways that a browser normally does that task, in other words.

Comment: `that don't answer my question`...it should, because it should give you the background knowledge to help you to understand, alongside my other comment, why `const dni = inputDNI.value; var result ="<?php buscarEnReniec(dni); ?>";` makes absolutely no sense at all, and cannot work.

Comment: I understood the concept, but i don't have idea about how i can do it. I'm new using Scriptcase and PHP.

Comment: Well there are about 3 million tutorials online which can show you how to use AJAX requests, if that's a new concept for you.

Comment: I checked tutorials, but i don't know what i would set in "url" key in ajax. I don't know how scriptcase manage the route to the functions in "PHP Methods" section or in a PHP function that is in the same file of the HTML code, like my example. Also I don't know how get and set variables between HTML and PHP in this case

Comment: Well I don't know much about scriptcase specifically, but I thought it was supposed to be a "low code" environment where you don't have to bother about the details of the actual code. Are you sure it doesn't have a widget for this sort of thing already? In an AJAX request though, if you set the URL as empty, it will just send the request to the same URL as the current page.

Comment: `I don't know how get and set variables between HTML and PHP`...to send the value from JS to PHP you send them as parameters of the HTTP AJAX request.

Comment: My question is about how can i do that in Scriptcase. I know that without Scriptcase this would be more eassier :c

Comment: Ah ok, sorry that wasn't very clear in the question - you seemed to just mention scriptcase as an incidental thing about your environment. And as I said, I don't really know anything about the product - other than that its marketing suggests you shouldn't ever have to dive this deep into code to get things done!